# rsRand() significantly slows down RenderScript

Tags: android, renderscript

I've been scratching my head over this for a bit and the only thing I can conclude is that `rsRand()` is not implemented on the processor that is usually meant to run the script (e.g. GPU or CPU) or that it cannot be run in parallel.

Can anyone confirm this? If that is the case, is there a reference somewhere listing what functions are safe to use in relation to performance?

Is there any other way to get a random number without using `rsRand()`?

Here is my renderscript file:

```
#pragma version(1)
#pragma rs java_package_name(com.example.app)
#pragma rs_fp_relaxed

float width;
float height;
float3 p0, p1, p2, p3;

uchar4 __attribute__((kernel)) gradGen(uint32_t x, uint32_t y)
{
  float3 result;
  float hd = x / width;
  float vd = y / height;
  float noise = rsRand((float) 1 / 256) - ((float) 1 / 512); // CULPRIT
  hd = 3 * hd * hd - 2 * hd * hd * hd;
  vd = 3 * vd * vd - 2 * vd * vd * vd;
  result.r = (1 - vd) * ((1 - hd) * p0.r + hd * p1.r) + vd * ((1 - hd) * p3.r + hd * p2.r) + noise;
  result.g = (1 - vd) * ((1 - hd) * p0.g + hd * p1.g) + vd * ((1 - hd) * p3.g + hd * p2.g) + noise;
  result.b = (1 - vd) * ((1 - hd) * p0.b + hd * p1.b) + vd * ((1 - hd) * p3.b + hd * p2.b) + noise;
  return rsPackColorTo8888(result);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rsRand()` calls the platform `rand()` on most implementations (that's how it's implemented in the CPU backend, I don't know that any RS GPU drivers actually implement RNGs in their drivers), so it's going to be significantly more heavyweight and slower than something like simple shifts and XORs.

and yeah, looking at the bionic implementation of `rand()`, you're right that it's serialized. maybe I'll get someone to port a Mersenne twister sometime.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of wondering, I decided to do the dumb thing and write my own `rsRand()`. [Xorshift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xorshift) was simple enough and here is extra code for implementing a [PRNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator):

```
uint32_t r0 = 0x6635e5ce, r1 = 0x13bf026f, r2 = 0x43225b59, r3 = 0x3b0314d0;

uchar4 __attribute__((kernel)) gradGen(uint32_t x, uint32_t y)
{
  ...
  // Generate a random number between 0-1
  uint32_t t = r0 ^ (r0 << 11);
  r0 = r1; r1 = r2; r2 = r3;
  r3 = r3 ^ (r3 >> 19) ^ t ^ (t >> 8);
  float rnd = (float) r3 / 0xffffffff;
  ...
}
```

The above is fast and the quality of random numbers are good enough for my application. I'd still be interested to know the details behind `rsRand()` slow down.